# R how to match and extract character letters of different length in a string

Tags: r, regex

So I have a column of contract names df$name like below

FB210618C00280000
ADM210618C00280000
M210618P00280000

I would like to extract the FB, ADM and M. That is I want to extract characters in the string and they are of different length and stop once the first number occurs, and I don't want to extract the C or P.

The below code will give me the C or P

```
stri_extract_all_regex(df$name, "[a-z]+")
```

Comment: Just to make it clear: do you want to extract `M` from a `2M210618C00280000` string?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew great comment. Luckily the US stocks don't have number starting in their tickers, like 3M company ticker is MMM. But oversea markets have werid tickers, like A2M210618C002345, so in that case, how could I get the A2M

Comment: `A2M`? What is the rule here? Match first letters and then an optional occurrence of a single digit followed with a letter that is not followed by another letter?

Comment: I hope you have solved this.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew hi sorry I was out of the town. For US contracts that I care at the moment, it is solved. For the other overseas contracts like A2M stuff, I frankly dont think there is a rule on how they abbreviated their names...

Comment: Ok, then, it is all clear now, you can use both solutions below.

Comment: yeah man, thank you.  And frankly I only use to know str_exact stuff, this stri_extract_first is awesome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `stri_extract_first` from `stringi`

```
library(stringi)
stri_extract_first(df$name, regex = "[A-Z]+")
#[1] "FB"  "ADM" "M"
```

---

Or we can use `base R` with `sub`

```
sub("\\d+.*", "", df$name)
#[1] "FB"  "ADM" "M"
```

Or use `trimws` from `base R`

```
trimws(df$name, whitespace = "\\d+.*")
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("FB210618C00280000", "ADM210618C00280000", 
    "M210618P00280000"))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```r
library(stringr)
str_extract(df$name, "^[A-Za-z]+")
# Or
str_extract(df$name, "^\\p{L}+")
```

The `stringr::str_extract` function will extract the first occurrence of a pattern and `^[A-Za-z]+` / `^\p{L}+` regex matches one or more letters at the start of the string. Note `\p{L}` matches any Unicode letters.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JuhtXT/1).

Same pattern can be used with `stringi::stri_extract_first()`:

```r
library(stringi)
stri_extract_first(df$name, regex="^[A-Za-z]+")
```

Comment: See [an online R demo](https://ideone.com/YnpSwZ) showcasing `stringr` solution, too.